# Hibernate: @OrderBy

Tags: java, hibernate

I have to order a list of child entities by dates.
Right now I am doing this way:

```
@OrderBy(clause = "arrivalDate ASC, arrivalTime ASC, departureDate ASC, departureTime ASC")
```

where arrivalDate and departureDate contains date, arrivalTime and departureTime contains time but all of them of type DATE.

Everything fine untill I add a new item to list - it always appears at the end of the list.
How can I solve it?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OrderBy clause is only used when Hibernate selected entities from the database. Once the list is in memory, it works as any other list in Java. If you add something to the list, the `List.add()` method works like it's documented in its javadoc, and the element is added at the end of the list.

If you want the new item to be inserted at the appropriate index in the list, you'll have to find this index yourself, or add it to the list and sort the list, using a Comparator which orders the items based on their arrival date, arrival time, etc.

And of course, be aware that if you change one of those fields in an item that is already in the list, the list won't have the rigth order anymore.

Maybe you should avoid the @OrderBy annotation completely, and simply add a `getSortedItems()` method in your entity, that would return a sorted copy of the list of items.

Comment: Another option is to use @org.hibernate.annotations.Sort which sets up a SortedSet/SortedMap with your supplied comparator.